# What is the name of this transition effect for two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll tell you right away that I'm new to this.

[image]

Comment: it's toggle-button. 

just google it and you'll find lot's of different implementations

Comment: Usually the text differs between the two choices of a toggle-button, though...

Comment: @YuliiaZ thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a toggle button. There should however be two different texts `Sign in` and `Sign up`.